# GNOME 3 Ctrl+Alt+D (Show Desktop)

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, desktop

I recently upgraded my system to GNOME 3. In previous versions of GNOME, the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> would hide all open windows and show the Desktop. This shortcut was eliminated from GNOME 3 along with the concept of a Desktop. The Desktop metaphor does, however, exist in GNOME 3 "fallback mode" (which I am using).

I would like to reinstate the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> keyboard shortcut. I know at least two ways of creating key combinations in GNOME. One is through System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts, and the other is through `gconf-editor` > apps > metacity. From either of these environments, I can pair a command with the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. The problem is that I don't know what command will trigger a "Show Desktop" event. Could someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Navigation > Hide all normal windows

Click the second field which says `Disabled` and type in a key combination of choice (e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).

System restart may be required for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using gnome3? If yes, you can go to the system settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts (if i'm not mistaken). Under one of the categories on the left, you should be able to set your own shortcut.

Comment: I recently upgraded to gnome3 but am now using fallback mode. Do you know what command will 'show desktop'? Another place I could do this is gconf-editor, but again I don't know what command to give. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new at answering q's and unsure if this would provide any help but did you try <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Here's the URL that I found pretty helpful: http://www.raizlabs.com/blog/29/keyboard-shortcut-dictionary-and-glossary-ctrl-shift-alt-f1

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that list is intended for Windows users. Probably I should have been more clear that I'm on a linux box.

Comment: Super + D is what does I have it set to in openbox. You should add that you're using gnome3 to your question.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>... is what I have to "hide all normal windows"... I am using Fallback mode in fedora 17, because I started to experience some flakiness with normal Gnome 3... which I like, btw, but I would have dialog boxes pop up all black and stuff... can't work with that.